# Translate pages and URLs without duplicating

Tags: translation, duplicates

I would really appreciate some suggestions about what plugin to use in WP with DIVI editor, to translate my web site and following these specs:

- do not duplicate pages (that's really important)
- translate page URLs,
- translate page visible text, as well as hidden text (meta tag values),
- keep in place existing page layouts and elements built with DIVI,

Actually I am not sure that is possible, having pages designed with DIVI.
I am playing with Polylang, but looks like is not possible to do all I need without duplicating pages.

Thank you all.
Fabio

Comment: Translating page URLs means you will have duplicate pages. If you don't want duplicates, the only way to avoid them is to use the original URLs, query strings, and canonicals that tell search engines not to spider the other languages - which will make it hard for visitors in other languages to find your site.

Answer (score 0):

The first question here is why don't you want to duplicate your pages?
I would very much advise to use a plugin like PolyLang or WMPL that do exactly that.

qTranslate X is a plugin that does not duplicate pages. It just copies the content of all translations into one post.
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

Comment: In my opinion duplication must be avoided as hell. If you duplicate a page to translate it, then later on you want to update some layout/widget (no text)/etc then you have to work twice or more. Please note that I'm not talking about standard WP pages, but pages designed with DIVI visual editor that puts a lot of stuff into a page. Thanks for suggesting qTranslate... Did you make it working with DIVI and translations without duplicating pages? Thanks

Comment: Ok, got your point now. qtranslate still duplicates the content (structure, etc.). So this will not solve your issue. 
The only way around this are those Javascript based translation widget like Google Translate. 
But if you work with a professional translation agency, duplicated pages are not an issue. You can just send all your content into translation again and they just bill you for what has changed. So you don't have to worry about layout.

Comment: You don't really have to write "Thank you" notes here, but upvoting or accepting an answer is always appreciated :-D